# Modifying WixUI_Font_Title

Tags: wix

Does anyone know how to change the defalut WixUI_Font_Title? I don't want to add all the forms to my WiX project just to give their title a new text style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WixUI_Font_Title` text style is just defined in `*.wxs` which describe the UI elements, but it is only used in `*.wxl` files where the titles are kept for various languages. So, if I were you I would go the following way:

- define the text style you need in your WiX sources, e.g. `WixUI_NewFont_Title`
- author a custom en-us WXL file, which includes all texts that reference the desired title font
- repeat the previous step for each languages you have to support

Comment: Hi Yan,Thanks. It worked and I could remove all the dialogs from my project.